# How to alias a module?

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, require, js-amd

Is it possible to add an alias to a module ?

For example I define a module like

`define('X')`

I would like to require it like this

`require(['Y'])`

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.8.0.min'
    }
    , urlArgs: urlArgs
});
require( ["jquery"],    function() {});
```